# Python How to use multiple for loops in list comprehension with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am still working on this below code, Code works perfectly fine. I am trying to reduce lines of code.

```
import calendar as c
def solve(first, last):
    weekends = []
    # x = [weekends.append(m) if c.weekday(y,m,1) == 4 and c.weekday(y,m,31) == 6 else 0 for m in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] for y in range(first,last+1)]
    for y in range(first,last+1):
        for m in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:
            if c.weekday(y,m,1) == 4 and c.weekday(y,m,31) == 6:
                weekends.append(m)
    return c.month_abbr[weekends[0]], c.month_abbr[weekends[len(weekends)-1]], len(weekends)
```

When Called for : `solve(2016,2020)`

This code returns the first month of 2016 which has 5 Fridays, Saturdays, Sundays; same for last month of 2020 and how many months satisfies this condition.

So OUTPUT is : `('Jan', 'May', 5)`

The comment part of x variable is what I tried and that returns 0 and None(cause of else statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of statements in your `x = ...` is a bit messed up; your `if` should filter which values to include, not which of two alternative values to use. But also: Do *not* use `append` in a list comprehension to append to another list! Instead, the list comprehension itself, should be your result.

```
def solve(first, last):
    weekends = [c.month_abbr[m] for y in range(first,last+1)
                                for m in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
                                if c.weekday(y,m,1) == 4]
    return weekends[0], weekends[-1], len(weekends)
```

Some minor points I fixed:

- get `month_abbr` directly in list comp instead of twice at the end
- `-1` in itself is a valid index
- the two weekday-checks are redundant

Comment: Thanks for your solution.